# How to make a img-div relation like Reddit did?

Tags: css, image

As you can see in image, even image size too high,we only see image size where Reddit let us see. The rest of image only can see by clicking button. There is no squeeze. So how could i do this?

Thank you.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Uj0I.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this. https://jsfiddle.net/x3gh29vt/1/

You create a container with a set height and width and hide the extra content with `overflow: hidden`

Then add an eventlistener to the button to toggle the container's overflow value;

Comment: Thank you! This is what i want. overflow:hidden. My problem solved!